# “Comment on something” or “comment something”?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, transitive-verbs

Do I say “comment on something” or simply “comment something”?

For example:

- Brian ?*commented on* this video.
- Brian ?*commented* this video

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The OED says that the usage without *on* or *upon* is now *“archaic”*:

> - **2**. **a.** *trans.* To furnish with comments; to make a comment or comments on; to annotate. *arch.* Hence **ˈcommented** *ppl. a*.
>
>   - 1599 Thynne *Animadv*. (1865) 75 ― Leysure to reprinte, correcte, and comente the same.
>   - 1641 Milton *Ch. Govt.* v. (1851) 119 ― Anselme··commenting the Epistles to Titus and the Philippians.
>   - 1695 Humfrey *Mediocria* 29, ― I comment therefore these words thus.
>   - 1700 Prior *Carmen Sec.* 158 ― To trace each Toil, and comment ev’ry War.
>   - 1768 Johnson *Pref. to Shaks.* Wks. IX. 285 ― The chief desire of him that comments an author.
>   - 1838–9 *Hallam Hist. Lit.* I. ɪ. iii. 149 ― The treatise was commented, abridged··and even turned into verse.
>   - 1904 *Nation* (N.Y.) 7 Apr. 272 ― Tennyson’s In Memoriam, commented by L. Morel.
>   - 1963 *Language* XXXIX. 242 ― This commented anthology.

Comment: I'm tempted to wonder whether it could mutate and end up with the prepositions being dropped in web contexts. It certainly hasn't happened yet though.

Comment: @JonHanna Some forums, it seems to have begun to occur. However, it's still not too widespread, at least where I usually browse.